# Ionic PWA with Workbox - Cached fonts not displaying

Tags: ionic2, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have configured my existing Ionic app as a PWA using workbox.  All seems to work fine in Firefox.  However in Chrome, both on Windows 10 and Android, a number of font files are not found in the cache.

[image]

I have verified that those files do exist in the cache:

[image: Proof that they do exist in the cache]

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?  Why can't the files be found in the cache?  The result is that my toolbar icons appear as empty rectangles.

**EDIT 18/11/2017**

My service worker code is very simple:

```
importScripts('workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.1.js');

const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW();
workboxSW.precache([]);
```

My workbox-cli-config.js file contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
    "maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes": "5MB",
    "globDirectory": "www\\",
    "globPatterns": [
        "**/*.{xod,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,ico,png,js,css,gif,html,cur,json,otf}"
    ],
    "globIgnores": [
        "..\\workbox-cli-config.js"
    ],
    "swSrc": "src/sw.js",
    "swDest": "www/sw.js"
};
```

Comment: can you also post that portion of your service worker?

Comment: @Niladri I've added my service worker code and config to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cache Storage API uses URLs as keys, and by default, the lookups are done using exact matches. So you're caching URLs like `assets/fonts/ionicons.woff2` but requesting URLs with an additional query parameter, like `assets/fonts/ionicons.woff2?v=3.0.0-alpha.3`, and that doesn't match.

You have a few options:

- Have you web app request the URLs without that `v=` parameter. (If you're using it to version your resources, consider adding in hashes to the filenames instead, and then precaching the URLs that include those hashed filenames.)
- Use the `ignoreUrlParametersMatching: [/^v$/]` [Workbox configuration parameter](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.Configuration) to ignore the `v=` query parameter when performing cache matches for precached resources.

(As an aside, every browser that supports service workers also supports WOFF2 fonts, so it's a waste to precache non-WOFF2 font resources. Only the WOFF2 format should need to be precached.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeff.  I'm struggling with using the ignoreUrlParametersMatching option.  I am using injectManifest().  The docs say that I must therefore pass the desired value in the WorkboxSW constructor.  I tried modifying the constructor in my swSrc file to: const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW([{ignoreUrlParametersMatching: [/^v$/]}]);   However this did not work. The font files are still not found. I'm guessing I've got the syntax wrong.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I worked it out.  I just needed quotes around ignoreUrlParametersMatching.  new self.WorkboxSW([{"ignoreUrlParametersMatching": [/^v$/]}]);